# How to include javascript from wp plugin to all pages on a website?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a plugin that has js file in its folder.

My main plugin file looks like this:

```
require('api/myapi.class.php'); // API Library 
require('settings.php'); // Configuration Options
require('register_shortcodes.php');
```

How to add a function that will inject js file to all client pages (Not admin pages)
I guess I need to use wp_enqueue_script but where should I add it?

```
wp_enqueue_script("myscript.js");
```

Comment: try this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: hope this will help you https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_scripts' );

function my_plugin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', plugins_url().'/plugin_name/js/myscript.js', array('jquery'));
}
```

This assumes you put your script in the js folder of the plugin folder, and that it depends on jquery.

EDIT:

A user tried to edit my answer, that added no real improvement to my answer. To explain my answer a bit more. You hook to `wp_enqueue_scripts` which will show the function with the enque script ***only*** on the front end, and not in the admin area, which is what the OP wanted, so there is really no need to check if you're on the admin page.